# How do I customise subclassing behaviour or require subclassing in a particular way?

Tags: python

Let's say I'm building a class called `ModelController`. I want this class to have a bunch of methods that can wrap a separate `Model` class, which is my database abstraction.

I want to be able to define a class method on `ModelController` like so:

```
ModelController():
  @classmethod
  def list(cls):
    cls.model.list()
  @classmethod
  def byName(cls, name):
    return cls.model(name)
```

And have Model class like this:

```
ArticleModel(Model):
    pass
```

And then do something like this:

```
ArticleModelController(ModelController):
  # ??? maybe:
  # model = ArticleModel
```

I suppose I could just subclass my Model classes for a controller and then have some kind of mixin pattern, but the reason I want the model to be a class attribute of the controller is that I really don't want to risk accidentally exposing some of its methods over HTTP when I mount this class in a cherrypy method dispatcher or something like that.

Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally un-pythonic or committing some kind of fallacy. Am I trying to do 'magic'?

edit: I just remembered my old days of Django and its ModelForms. They work like this:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

Perhaps this is what I should be looking at. Is it possible to validate that this 'model' attribute is defined and throw an error if something is subclassed without it being undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This* is metaclasses:

```
class ModelControllerMetaclass(type):
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    if 'options' not in dct or not hasattr(dct['options'], 'model'):
      raise RuntimeError('You accidentally the model!')
    dct['_model'] = dct['options'].model
    # Some more manipulation of dct['options']
    del dct['options']
    type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class ModelController(object):
  __metaclass__ = ModelControllerMetaclass
  class options:
    model = None

class ArticleModelController(ModelController):
  class options:
    model = 'Some model goes here'

class InvalidModelController(ModelController):
  pass
```

And upon running:

```
$ python t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 19, in <module>
    class InvalidModelController(ModelController):
  File "t.py", line 4, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('You accidentally the model!')
RuntimeError: You accidentally the model!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out. I thought the metaclass might be the solution, but I'd read so much stuff saying you're probably doing something wrong unless you definitely know that you need a metaclass. It's giving the exact behaviour I want, though. Here's my `ModelController` class:

```
class ModelController():
  @classmethod
  def list(cls):
    return cls.meta.model.list()

  def __init__(self):
    self.model = self.__class__.meta.model
```

Then I can have a Model:

```
class ArticleModel():
  @classmethod
  def list(cls):
    # logic to retrieve the list of things fitting this class
```

Then finally, in my actual `Controller`, which I will mount in `cherrypy`:

```
class ArticleController():
  class meta:
    model = ArticleModel

  def index(self):
    article_list = self.model.list()
    return render(article_list)

  index.exposed = True
```

Is this Evil? Is it magic, not explicit enough? Are my Ruby roots showing? From this point on all I need to do is define new Models and Controllers, and if I forget to define a `model` attribute in the metaclass for my controller, it will throw an error when my mounted methods try to call stuff on the model.